# non-fully-qualified-frame_id how to fix?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @All,
please can you explain me, whats the the reason for this warning and how to fix it.

I get this [WARN][...]: Message from [/laserscanner-tcp] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser]...

Allthough its a warning I ignored but maybe its a good idea to fix it, but have no idea how.

Thanks

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65521/non-fully-qualified-frame_id-how-to-fix?/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's missing a tf prefix. The frame id laser could be resolved to /laser (a "world-wide" frame id) or /robot_a/laser (a robot-specific frame id).

If there is not tf prefix (i.e. you are not doing multirobot stuff) resolving laser to /laser is fine and shouldn't give you any problems.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1